# Kubuntu 18.04: HDMI audio stops working after idle

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio

Running a new install of Kubuntu 18.04 on Dell Optiplex 9020.

My display and audio are connected through a display port to my television. Problem is whenever my machine has been idle for >1 hour, the HDMI audio no longer works. Currently the only fix I have is to reboot the machine.

I have tried the following:

- Disabling all power-saving settings in System Settings
- Ensuring everything is unmuted in alsamixer
- Commenting out the line marked "load-module module-suspend-on-idle" in /etc/pulse/default.pa
- `pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1` (this does not return an error but neither does it change the default)
- `sudo killall pulseaudio`

Extra notes:

- Logging in and out does not fix the issue, only restarting.
- Suspending the machine and then unsuspending it does not replicate the issue.

Output when I run pacmd list-sinks

https://pastebin.com/HHjSV4Li

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, by reading up on DPMS here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling#Disabling_DPMS

What ended up working for me was to disable DPMS through xset, with

> xset -dpms